# How to advise users that have questions closed as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, review-queues, duplicate-questions, help-improvement

I have been a member of SO for around 6 months now.

One thing which is struck me that is:

I frequently see that when a new or existing user has a problem which has been  answered before, it has been closed as a **Duplicate**. The user is then redirected to the duplicate target. If the duplicate does not meet his requirement and he/she has not found an answer by using it, how can we help them to overcome this as the question is now closed. Even after the user makes changes to the question, there appears to be a very few reviewers interested in **reopening** the question.

I have seen many posts where a user commented after the question has being marked as a **Duplicate**, that the duplicate answer does not meet his/her requirements or the available answer is slightly different.

As a reviewer with 3000+ reputation, how can I help this user whose question has already been closed by other reviewers.

Comment: Encourage the other user to edit the question and explain why it's not the same. Once that's done, if you agree it's different, vote to reopen.

Comment: First and for all the *question* should be edit to include the link to said duplicate and showing, best with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), why any of the provided answer didn't work. It is the responsibility of the OP to clarify why the duplicate doesn't apply in their case or what sets their context apart from others. When done correctly re-opening should not be a problem. Only saying, specially in comments, *this is not duplicate* or *answers there don't help* is not and never will be a reason to re-open a question.

Comment: A question asker saying _"the duplicate doesn't answer my question"_ does not magically make it not a duplicate.

Comment: I just followed the idea told by @RobertLongson and opened one closed question.

Comment: and I'm sure I'll use your idea too Mr @CodeCaster.

Comment: As always with such questions, a link to an example question you find undeservedly closed as duplicate would greatly help your argument.

Comment: Über-Meta guidance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476/248731. In most cases only the OP has enough information to make the required edits, there's nothing you can (or should) do.

Comment: The person who asked the question that has since been closed as a duplicate is provided with *loads* of information on how to go about getting their question re-opened if they do not believe it is a duplicate. If they are unwilling to help themselves, you cannot help them.

Comment: "It isn't a duplicate because it wasn't good enough for me" *drops mike*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally it is not possible to "help" OP to reopen question after it is closed as duplicate. Users already given guidance that they need to edit question (in the closure banner) - unfortunately significant portion of user unable to read anything that is not copy-paste ready...

There are some cases where you actually can help:

- you've read question differently - comment to OP and possibly people who voted to close to clarify if your version of the question is one OP had in mind.
- know how OP pick absolutely wrong words to describe problem. I.e. for C# "get attribute of my struct" when they actually wanted to "assign property of instance of my class" - people frequently use random words to describe well defined concepts of particular languages thus making for totally different duplicate targets. Note that if updated question is still duplicate of some other post make sure to add comment with link to new duplicate so others can quickly re-open/close appropriately.
- OP ignored "edit post" advise and posted whole bunch of <s>moaning</s> good explanations as comments. Feel free to edit those comments in and consider if vote to re-open is appropriate at the point. Note that if you don't find post deserving upvote after your edit you probably just wasted your time...

You can also do what you should not do: edit post to whatever you feel is good question on the topic and completely ignore what OP said... Why would you do that instead of asking your own question? If you really feel there is something to the question - ask your own follow up question and provide link in the original.

Comment: I'm very please to get this answer, Very helpful for discussion.

Comment: Did you deliberately misspell "struct" ("stuct")?

Comment: @PeterMortensen no... fixed.